# Передача данных в comboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

С помощью combobox пытаюсь изменять размер изображение. Делаю это вот таким образом. Но не могу понять, почему в comboBox ничего не отображается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема и как можно её исправить?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setFixedSize(QSize(width(), height()));

    QString pic = " ";
    ui->lineEdit->setText(pic);

    QPixmap pix;
    pix.load(pic);
    //ui->label_photo->resize(pix.size());
    ui->label_photo->setPixmap(pix);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

QString MainWindow::pic()
{
    return ui->lineEdit->text();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString photo = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"load img",QString(),"Images (*.jpg *png)");
    ui->lineEdit->setText(photo);
    ui->label_photo->setPixmap(photo);
    qDebug()<<photo;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QImage picture (ui->lineEdit->text());
    picture.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(picture));
    QRgb tc = qRgb (243, 88, 165);
      for (int i = 0; i < picture.width(); i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < picture.height(); j++)
          {
              if (picture.pixel(i, j)== qRgb(0, 0, 0))
              {
                  picture.setPixel(i, j, tc);
              }
              }
          }
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(picture));
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QImage picture;
    picture.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
    QMatrix matrix;
    matrix.scale(-1, 1);
    picture = picture.transformed(matrix);
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(picture));

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
//    QPixmap pic2;
//    pic2.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
//    QSize PicSize(500, 500);
//    pic2 = pic2.scaled(PicSize,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
//    ui->label_2->setPixmap(pic2);
//    ui->label_2->repaint();
}

void MainWindow::on_comboBox_activated(const QString &arg1)
{
    if (arg1 == "500x500") {
            QPixmap pic2;
            pic2.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
            QSize PicSize(500, 500);
            pic2 = pic2.scaled(PicSize,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
            ui->label_2->setPixmap(pic2);
            ui->label_2->repaint();
            qDebug()<<pic2;

    }
    else if (arg1 == "700x700") {
        QPixmap pic2;
        pic2.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
        QSize PicSize(700, 700);
        pic2 = pic2.scaled(PicSize,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(pic2);
        ui->label_2->repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: не понятно что должно меняться в комбобоксе, также уточните с каким сигналом соединена функция on_comboBox_activated

Comment: В комбобоксе должны появляться для выбора записи "500х500" и "700х700".

Comment: Наверное потому что записи "500х500" и "700х700" надо добавить в комбобокс. Где код, который заполняет комбобокс?

Comment: Я добавил строки через форму.

Comment: сложно понять, в приведенном коде не видно соединения комбобокса со слотом, также не понятно что и как вы добавили в сам комбобокс

Comment: Всё, разобрался и всё получилось! Всем спасибо, кто откликнулся на помощь!

Comment: @EgaNator , стоит написать ответ на свой вопрос, чтобы те, кто его нагуглит смогли бы увидеть, как удалось решить проблему...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем корректно передал комбобоксу наименования.
Изменения масштаба я переделал таким образом:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    int i = ui->comboBox->currentIndex();


    switch (i) {
    case 0: {    
        QPixmap pic2;
        pic2.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
        QSize PicSize(320, 200);
        pic2 = pic2.scaled(PicSize,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(pic2);
        ui->label_2->repaint();
        break;
    }

    case 1: {
        QPixmap pic2;
        pic2.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
        QSize PicSize(640, 350);
        pic2 = pic2.scaled(PicSize,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(pic2);
        ui->label_2->repaint();
        break;
    }

    case 2: {
        QPixmap pic2;
        pic2.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
        QSize PicSize(640, 480);
        pic2 = pic2.scaled(PicSize,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(pic2);
        ui->label_2->repaint();
        break;
    }

    case 3: {
        QPixmap pic2;
        pic2.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
        QSize PicSize(800, 600);
        pic2 = pic2.scaled(PicSize,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(pic2);
        ui->label_2->repaint();
        break;
    }

    case 4: {
        QPixmap pic2;
        pic2.load(ui->lineEdit->text());
        QSize PicSize(1024, 768);
        pic2 = pic2.scaled(PicSize,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(pic2);
        ui->label_2->repaint();
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;

    }
}
```